# module import pickle behavior

Tags: python, pickle

I am saving a sklearn estimator that relies on the import of a module named `foo`.

The script is like that :

```
from foo import *
import pickle
import sklearn

estimator = ...

pickle.dump(estimator, open('file', 'wb'))
```

However, when trying to reload that estimator in another script :

```
import pickle
estimator = pickle.load(open('file', 'rb'))
```

I am getting the following error :
`` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `foo` ``

Although foo is actually not needed, I used it just to build the estimator, but to use it to make predictions for example, foo is not needed.

Any thoughts on how to solve that?

I tried to use the dill library and save the function in foo in the same pickle file but still getting the error.

Comment: You are using foo while model building and when you are saving it to file using pickle , you are dumping that with the file. So that's the reason its expecting while prediction

Comment: What would be the easiest way to solve that? I could add the functions locally but I do not want having to rerun the first script. Is there a way to get rid of this dependency in the pickle file?

Comment: when you define it in the import it does not affect the pickle.load method unless or other wise foo has to do something with the model creation and dumping the model in the file. How is the external script related to model creaton / Kindly paste the code which is part of the foo script which could be a little helpful.